# What are free variables?

Tags: javascript, closures, free-variable

Javascript closure definition says :

> A "closure" is an expression (typically a function) that can have free
>   variables together with an environment that binds those variables
>   (that "closes" the expression).

Can some one explain to me the concept of free variables ? Is this concept Javascript specific or applies to other languages also ?

Comment: A free variable is simply a variable which is not declared inside a given function, but is used inside it.

Comment: By the way, all global variables are free variables, but not all the free variables are global.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Free variables are simply the variables that are neither locally declared nor passed as parameter.

[Source :](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variable)

> In computer programming, the term free variable refers to variables
>   used in a function that are not local variables nor parameters of that
>   function.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variable) The term non-local variable is often a synonym in this
>   context.

In javascript closures, those are simply the variables that the function takes (read and write) in the enclosing scope where is declared the closure or in a parent scope.

Look at this real world example :

```
Gol.prototype._ensureInit = function() {
    ...
    var _this = this;
    var setDim = function() {
        _this.w = _this.canvas.clientWidth;
        _this.h = _this.canvas.clientHeight;
        _this.canvas.width = _this.w;
        _this.canvas.height = _this.h;
        _this.dimChanged = true;
        _this.draw();
    };
    setDim();
    window.addEventListener('resize', setDim);
    ...
};
```

In this example a closure points from the `setDim` function towards the variable `_this` declared in the enclosing scope (the `_ensureInit` function). This variable isn't declared in `setDim` nor passed. It's a *"free variable"*.

Note that `_this` doesn't become a variable of the function `setDim` : another function declared in the same scope would share the same variable.

Comment: "In this context, those are simply the variables that the function takes (read and write) in the enclosing scope where is declared the closure." not sure what you meant there ? Can you explain with an example , may be ?

Comment: @Geek I added a real world example

Answer (score 8):

A "free-translation" could be: `"out of scope" - variables`.

Since ECMAscript uses lexical scoping, a free variable is a variable which was defined in a parent-scope and gets looked-up by a scope-chain search.

```
(function _outerScope() {
    var foo = 42;

    (function _innerScope() {
        var bar = 100;

        console.log( foo + bar ); // 142
    }());
}());
```

In the above example, `foo` is a *free variable* within the context of `_innerScope`. it becomes very obvious if we have a quick glance into the underlying concepts of ECMAscript.

A *Context* is linked to an *Activation Object* (in ES3), respectively a *Lexical Enviroment Record* (in ES5), which contains things like: `function declarations`, `variables declared with var` and `formal paramters`, as well as a reference to all *parent Activation Objects* / *Lexical Environments*. If a variable needs to be accessed, the ECMAscript engine will first look into the *AOs* / *LEs* from the current *Context* itself; if it can't be found there, it looks into the parent *AO*'s / *LE*'s.

Since any *Context* stores this data in an *array-like structure* (don't forget we're talking about implementation level here, not Javascript itself), we are talking about `Lexical Scope`, because we search through all parent *Contexts* in order.

Answer (score 2):

As an example:

```
var myModule = (function (){
   var moduleVar; // closure variable

   return function(){
     // actual function
   }
})();
```

the variable defined there is a closure variable. it can be used all over the closure itself but is not part of a global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how many times I've read JS books and revise some topic in which the closure topic is there.

The answer is just an addition to the accepted answer.

The following example is excerpted from [Modern JavaScript for the Impatient,
Cay Horstmann](http://horstmann.com/javascript-impatient/)

```
// text is a free variable of the arrow function.
const sayLater = (text, when) => {
  //         vv
  let task = () => console.log(text) // (heed no 'text' variable here) => console.log(text)
  setTimeout(task, when)
}
```

Now you can grasp the meaning of

> The term free variable refers to variables used in a function that are
> not local variables nor parameters of that function.