# Authoring first jQuery plugin: understanding this

Tags: jquery

I've made a simple carousel for my site and I want to take it to the next step. I would like to have several carousels on a page and I'd like to just call `$('.carousel').swapify()` and be done with it.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
$.fn.swapify = function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log('this is currently: ' + this.selector);

  function advanceSlide() {
    $('.swapify li:first-child').appendTo('.swapify');
  }

  $(this).find('li').click(function() { advanceSlide(); });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.carousel').swapify();
});
```

When I interact with a carousel they all advance. This is pretty obvious, but I'm not sure how to make the interaction specific. I've tried something like:

```
$('li:first-child', this).appendTo(this);
```

I'm still developing my javascript vocabulary and it's proving hard to google.

edit: I setup a fiddle to illustrate this problem http://jsfiddle.net/69FM7/1/

Comment: I'm not sure of the actual problem, but a couple of things to tidy up: Firstly, be careful with similarly named variables: you define `$this`, but then use `this.selector` and `$(this).find`. Secondly, you don't need to wrap `advanceSlide` in an extra function; just `.click(advanceSlide)` will do (I personally prefer the more explicit `.on('click', advanceSlide)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extending the jQuery prototype (`jQuery.fn`), the function you write is given as `this` *the complete jQuery object passed in*, which in this case is the result of `$('.carousel')`, i.e. a collection of all elements with the class `carousel`. Therefore everything you do involving `this` applies to that entire collection.

What you want to do, and indeed what is very common in such cases, is act individually on *each element in the collection*. To do that, you can use [the `.each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to run the same function on every element. Each time the function is run, `this` is set to a single DOM element - not a jQuery object, which is why you need to re-wrap it with `$(this)`.

Since the function has its own scope, your use of `var $this = $(this)` allows you to create "closures", which carry the particular element around with them. Because it was declared inside the same scope, the function `advanceSlide` is such a closure - each time your function runs, new variables are created for both `$this` and `advanceSlide`.

Make sure you always use `$this`, though, as the actual `this` variable will be different when the function runs than when it was defined. (The click-handler will set it to the element that was clicked on.) For this reason, it might be better to use a different variable name, say, `$carousel` to remember which object it refers to.

Since `advanceSlide` is already a local function, you don't need another `function() { }` wrapper, just pass it in to the `.click()` (or `.on()`) call.

So what you end up with is the below, [as demoed in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sWUR5/4/):

```
$.fn.swapify = function () {
    // Here, `this` is a jQuery collection with multiple elements in
    this.each(function () {
        // Here, `this` is a single DOM node

        // using `var`, we make a variable bound to this scope
        // while we're at it, we wrap the DOM node with jQuery
        // Rather than $this, I've named the variable something meaningful
        var $carousel = $(this);

        // Declaring a function in the same scope as our var
        // creates a "closure",  which can always see the scope it was created in
        function advanceSlide() {
            // When this runs, it will be in response to a click,
            // and jQuery will set `this` to the element clicked on

            // Our $carousel variable, however, is carried in the closure,
            // so we know it will be the container we want
            $carousel.find('li:first-child').appendTo($carousel);
        }

        // A function in JS is just another kind of object, 
        // so we can pass in advanceSlide like any variable
        $carousel.find('li').on('click', advanceSlide);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swapify').swapify();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

IMSoP's answer is probably what you intended, but another options is to use delegated events:

```
$.fn.swapify = (function() {
    function advanceSlide(e) {
        var $carousel = $(e.delegateTarget);
        $carousel.find('li:first-child').appendTo($carousel);
    }

    return function swapify() {    
        this.on("click", "li", advanceSlide);
    };
}());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMYtE/4/)

---

Here are some quick explanations of some key concepts:

- [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

  IIFE's give you a way to make a stable new scope for new variables and functions to live in. We create a function and immediately invoke it.

  ```
  (function() {
      // new scope here   
  }());
  ```

  We are using one here to make a new scope for a single instance of the `advanceSlide` and `swapify` functions to live in.
- [Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and [Free Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934929/what-are-free-variables)

  The return value from the IIFE is the `swapify` function. This function is a closure – it closes over the free variable `advanceSlide`. "Free" in the sense that variable `advanceSlide` "escapes" along with `swapify` when it is returned out of the function – it is free to live beyond it's containing scope.
- `$.fn` is a alias of the jQuery's [`prototype` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). In short, this means that all instances of a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) will have access to  functions defined by the prototype.

  For clarity, `$("someselector")` will return a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery). We assign the return value of the IIFE to `$.fn.swapify` which will imbue jQuery objects our new functionality.
- [Delegated Events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

  When we invoke our `swapify` helper, instead of binding events on each `li` – which is what `.find("li").on(...)` would do – it would be ideal to bind events on the parent element. *Then* let jQuery dynamically check that the `target` of the event matches the set we care about.

  For example, you may have only a handful of `ul` elements, however each one of those may contain hundreds of `li` elements. Rather than needing to create a handler and attach an event on each one of those, we can simply attach a single handler on the parent. This minimizes the number of event handlers that need to be bound.
- Using the [`delegatedTarget` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) from the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

  Finally, when our event handler gets invoked it will be passed an [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). That will have several useful properties, like `target`, `currentTarget`, and `delegatedTarget`. We use `delegatedTarget` to look up the root element that we originally bound to, and assign that to `$this`. Then, the rest of your logic works the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this via below:

```
$.fn.swapify = function() {
  $.each($(this), function(index, element) {
    var $this = $(this);

    function advanceSlide() {
       $this.find('li:first-child').appendTo($this);
    }

    $this.find('li').click(function() { advanceSlide(); });
  });
}
```

As `$this` denotes to the specific selector for which swapify get bind.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69FM7/4/)**

This will fix your issue.

Comment: This didn't work, check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/69FM7/1/

Every time you click an li, that li gets appended to all `.swapify`

Comment: @riot, i have fixed the issue and attached the demo fiddle. Have a look now.

Comment: One optimisation noted in my answer: `this` will already be a jQuery object when `.swapify()` is run, so you can just do `this.each` rather than `$(this).each` or `$.each($(this),`