# Difference between free variable and local free variable

Tags: javascript, closures

I am reading a tutorial about javascript closure.There is a concept called free variables.Free variables are variables that are neither **locally declared** nor passed as a parameter.

### The tutorial's first example:

```js
function numberGenerator() {
  // Local “free” variable that ends up within the closure
  var num = 1;
  function checkNumber() { 
    console.log(num);
  }
  num++;
  return checkNumber;
}

var number = numberGenerator();
number();
```

In this example, the comment said num is a local free variable.But the above concept about free variable said a free variable is not locally declared.I am confusing about that.

Comment: I think in this case the naming as "free" variable is misleading.

Comment: You are not the first asking this have a look a this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934929/what-are-free-variables

Answer (score 0):

The right term in this case is a `locally declared variable` (local to the numberGenerator()).

This definition could help you to understand a closure:

> A closure is the local variables for a function - kept alive after the
>   function has returned.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you question is but num is only availible within the closure its considered a "private" variable of numberGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

So `num` is a local to the `numberGenerator()` function. If you try to access or use it outside of this function, it would return an error. Check the below code, at the last line, I have `console.log()` and used `num` but it throws an error and doesn't give any value, that's because `num` is local to `numberGenerator()` function and can be used only inside it:

```js
function numberGenerator() {
  // Local “free” variable that ends up within the closure
  var num = 1;
  console.log('Value inside numberGenerator: ' + num);

  function checkNumber() {
    console.log('Value inside checkNumber: ' + num);
  }
  num++;
  return checkNumber;
}

var number = numberGenerator();
number(); // 2
console.log('Callling from outside functions: ' + num);
```